# line chart plots

Tags: python, pandas

I've been struggling with this code on airpassengers dataset in python 3.5

```
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import Grouper
from matplotlib import pyplot

series = read_csv('AirPassengers.csv', header=None, index_col=0, 
parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)
groups = series['1949':'1960'].groupby(Grouper(freq='A'))
years = DataFrame()
pyplot.figure()
i = 1
n_groups = len(groups)
for name, group in groups:
    pyplot.subplot((n_groups*100) + 10 + i)
    i += 1
    pyplot.plot(group)
pyplot.show()
```

I get the following errors:

```
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '1949'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that you use [Kaggle AirPassengers](https://www.kaggle.com/rakannimer/air-passengers/version/1) dataset. It has a header, so you should omit `header=None`.

```
series = read_csv('AirPassengers.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)

groups = series['1949':'1960'].groupby(Grouper(freq='A'))
pyplot.figure()
i = 1
n_groups = len(groups)
```

And for subplot: you can use subplot(xyz) but note that all integers (x, y, z) must be less than 10 for this form to work.

```
for name, group in groups:
    pyplot.subplot(n_groups, 1, i)
    i += 1
    pyplot.plot(group)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the code to run.  Why wouldn't the header=None in read_csv not ignore the dataset header?

Comment: any way you could help me with a boxplot too.  Sorry I'm learning python and I'm running into a few hurdles.

    series = read_csv('AirPassengers.csv', header=None, index_col=0, 
    parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)
    groups = series['1964':'1970'].groupby(Grouper(freq='A'))
    years = DataFrame()
    for name, group in groups:
      years[name.year] = group.values
    years.boxplot()
    pyplot.show()